# Assigning values to two dimensional array in c

Tags: c, arrays, gcc, char

I have written a piece of code for finding the continuous sum equal to one of the argument provided.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    //number of test case
    int n;
    int monfri[2];

    scanf("%d",&n);

    char res[n][3] ;
    char yestok[3] = {"YES"};

    int sum = 0;
    int h = 0;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < n; i++)
    {
        h=0;
        //read no of friends and money
        while (h < 2 && scanf("%d", &monfri[h]) == 1)
            h++;

        int fri[monfri[0]];

        for(int j = 0; j < monfri[0]; j++)
            scanf("%d",&fri[j]);


        for(int k = 0; k < monfri[0] ; k++)
        {
            sum = 0;

            for(int l=k+1; l<monfri[0]; l++)
            {
                sum = sum + fri[l - 1];

                if(sum == monfri[1])
                {
                    strcpy (res[i],yestok);
                    continue;
                }

                if(sum > monfri[i])
                    continue;
            }
        }       

        if(strcmp(res[i],yestok) != 0)
        {
            strcpy (res[i],"NO");       
        }

    }

    for(int d = 0; d < n ; d++)
    {
        puts(res[d]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

providing the input for the same

```
2
5 12
2
3
4
5
6
3 15
2
2
2
```

Here first input represents the no of test case in our case its 2

the next input represents actual no of data and sum value. here its

```
5 12
3 15
```

The expected output should be

```
YES
NO
```

But I am getting

```
YESNO
NO
```

What wrong I did. If no of test case is 1 then it works fine. but failed in 2 or more test cases.

Comment: have you tried debugging? This is a straight "Please debug my program" question.

Comment: @bolov I tried but I could not find any. `strcmp` and other thing are fine it seems and conditions are also ok it seems.

Comment: At the very least debugging will narrow your suspicions to where the bug comes from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string "YES" needs space of 4 chars. Thus, you must change the declaration of `yestok` to

```
char yestok[4] = {"YES"};
```

or even better, let the compiler determine the length:

```
char yestok[] = {"YES"};
```

Otherwise, the terminating NUL character gets lost and your program invokes undefined behaviour. For example the `strcmp` call may fail.

Comment: @MarthinZabel Thanks your explanation, here the `strcmp` seems to be ok. I am getting expected results. but as you said, due to undefined behavior it actually prints till it gets '\0'. Thus I couldn't able to figure it out.